# Instagram geographies request

Tags: node.js, express, instagram

I'm trying through node.js and express to build an app that will fetch Instagram pictures taken in a certain geography (area). However, I don't know how to create the geography subscription id. According to Instagram API, this ID is unique and is created for each geography subscription.

Can anyone help?

Each time I put the longitude, latitude and radius, I get an error message in my command line from Instagram: `APInotfounderror: this geography does not exist in request`.

Answer (score 0):

The geography id is created automatically when you create the geography subscription. The geography ID is included in each update notification in the field "object_id". You can also list the information on your existing subscriptions with:

https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions?client_id=ID&client_secret=SECRET

Your response will be along the lines of:

```
{"meta":{"code":200},
  "data":{
    "object":"geography",
    "object_id":"GEOGRAPHYID",
    "aspect":"media",
    "callback_url":"example.com/callback",
    "type":"subscription",
    "id":"SUBSCRIPTIONID"
  }
}
```